# How to use value from one python script to another

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I have 2 python scripts.

Script1.py includes:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    exec(open("script2.py").read())
    
def main():
    global entry_field
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry_field = tk.Entry(root)
    entry_field.pack()

    button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me!", command=button_click)
    button.pack()  

    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Second python script is "Script2" and includes:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import script1

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text=script1.entry_field.get())
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

My idea is: I want to pass value which I typed into entry field in script1.py, after I want to use this value and show it with label on script2.py.

When I run this code I'm getting an error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Skaala\Skaala project\Test folder\script1.py", line 4, in button_click
    exec(open("script2.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'script1' has no attribute 'entry_field'
```

I will appreciate for any help.

**EDIT:**

I've changed code a little bit, and removed "if **name** == "**main**":" statement, and now it works on half way. When I run "Script1.py" it opening twice. Thats why I used "if **name** == "**main**":", because "Script2.py" importing data from "Script1.py" and it runs full script again.

[image: Program runs twice]

Comment: if you need those two scripts to remain separate, i.e. different processes, then there is no instant way of doing it. you will need to share data either via a database, a file,  or a communication protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is: I want to pass value which I typed into entry field in
> script1.py, after I want to use this value and show it with label on
> script2.py.

It is not recommended to use `exec(open("script2.py").read())`. It is merely to read, not import module.

You cannot swap from `script2.py` to `script1.py` and vice-versa, otherwise, you will freeze and not respond. It will take about 15 or more minutes.

On `script1.py` module:

Use `root = tk.Tk()` and `root.mainloop()` entirely script instead of duplicating.

We can put `root = tk.Tk()` at the top before the function. In that case, we can use `root` to pass to any modules.

- On the `button_click()` function, just called `script2` module using
  `import script2`.
- And called `Script2.run()` function.
- Remove `root.mainloop()` on the button_click() function.

On `script2.py` module:

- You need to called second window using `Toplevel`. Otherwise, you
  will not see print output.
- Create `run()` function, and add two parameters. In that we can call from
  `button_click()` `script1` module. And declare variable `core`. So we can pass `root` to `core`.

Snippet `script1.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def button_click():        
    import Script2
    g = entry_field.get()
    Script2.run(root, g)
  
def main():
    global entry_field
    root.title('Main Window')
     
    entry_field = tk.Entry(root)
    entry_field.pack()

    button = tk.Button(
        root,
        text="Click me!",
        command=button_click
        )
    button.pack()  

    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

script2.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
 
def run(core, data):
    core = tk.Toplevel()
    core.title("Toplevel")
    label_2 = tk.Label(core, text=data)    
    label_2.pack()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the point of the argument `core` in function `run()` because it is overwritten at the beginning of the function?

Comment: It is just variable core = root

Comment: It is not necessary because it is not used and overwritten inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

`entry_field`, `button` and `root` only exist inside the scope of the function `main` in Script1. If you want to access them outside the `main` function, you need to move their declaration outside the function into the global scope.

Edit:

In Python, classes and functions define *scope*. Scope is what determines what labels refer to what values. If you declare something inside a function, that value will only be accessible inside that function's scope. I.e, anything inside the function body. In the example below, we have a global declaration `g = 1` and a function `f1` that assigns `g = 2`. Note that this is *NOT THE SAME `g`*. It's creating an entirely new label for an entirely new value.

```py
g = 1

def f1():
    # Creates a local variable g which is
    # different from the global variable g
    # and is not visible outside the function.
    # The value is 2, but the global g is still 1.
    g = 2

def f2():
    # This time, the variable g is declared
    # as global, so any references to g inside
    # f2 will refer to the global g.
    global g
    g = 2

def f3():
    # This time the code will actually crash with
    # an UnboundLocalError, because the we're trying
    # to assign the local variable g at the same time
    # as we're trying to read the global variable g.
    g += 1

f1()
print(g) #prints 1

f2()
print(g) #prints 2

f3() # crashes
```

The `exec` function takes an input string and runs it in the current scope, so the code you included in your answer is actually equivalent to this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    # This line:
    # exec(open("script2.py").read())

    # Is the same as just pasting the code here:
    import tkinter as tk
    import script1

    root = tk.Tk()

    label = tk.Label(root, text=script1.entry_field.get())
    label.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    
def main():
    global entry_field
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry_field = tk.Entry(root)
    entry_field.pack()

    button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me!", command=button_click)
    button.pack()  

    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This becomes a problem because Script1 will only have the attribute `entry_field` *after `main` has been called*.

It's not clear to me why you're putting this into two separate files and "importing" Script2 by calling `exec` on it. Why are you doing that? There are better ways of splitting up code between files, such as just doing `import <filename>`. `exec` should generally be used very sparingly.

Comment: I edit my question a little bit, please check.

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't fix the actual problem. I'll update my answer to clarify.